# Parse, can't delete PFObject from iOS app?

Tags: ios, parse-platform

I am trying to delete an object my current user (PFUser) points to:

```
PFObject * objectB = currentUser[@"B"];
[objectB fetchIfNeeded];
BOOL deleted = [objectB delete];
[currentUser @"B"];
```

deleted is **FALSE.**

I get an error saying:

```
Error: object not found for delete (Code: 101, Version: 1.2.19)
```

Every time I try to do this I check on the server and the "B" object is there, so why is it telling me "object not found..."?

**How do I delete an object another object points to?** I have a valid reference to "B" from current user right before I try to do this. I go in the data browser, I go to current user and click on B pointer and it takes me to the right object...

Any idea?

Comment: are you using ACL? does the current user have the privileges to delete the object?

Comment: the only ACL I set is this on "B": PFACL * acl = [PFACL ACL]; [acl setPublicReadAccess:YES];. So, maybe that is what I am not understanding. I need to specify certain ACLS to be able to delete objects that were created by the user?

Comment: In B in the data browser I see these ACLS:  {"*":{"read":true}}

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When creating your B object, try and use the following ACL:

```
PFACL *acl = [PFACL ACLWithUser:[PFUser currentUser]];
[acl setPublicReadAccess:YES];
BObject.ACL = acl;
```

This will give the current user full privileges on B and set read prevailed for all.

When you use

```
[PFACL ACL];
```

you get an empty ACL, so to say, that you can then further specify using:

```
[acl setReadAccess:YES forUser:user];
[acl setWriteAccess:YES forUser:user];
```

giving read/write access to each user individually.

Also have a look at the [Parse iOS Dev Guide](https://parse.com/docs/ios_guide#top/iOS), it has a very nice introduction to ACLs (search for ACL in the page).

Comment: works great now. I assumed that the current user could do anything on the objects the I create while logged in as the current user... So, the way I understand it now, no matter what I have to be specific about the the ACL for any object I create. With this answer I can now delete "B" while logged in with the user that created it and also read "B" from any user. Thanks.

Comment: I suppose that if you do not specify any ACL, then the user that created the object has full privileges; if you specify an ACL, then your ACL rules. In this case you ACL was only giving read privileges to anyone. In any case, glad that it helped.

Comment: Sergio, what do you think, will this solution work if I'm using the master key in a cloud code?